# jquery - get xml param

Tags: jquery, xml, string, object

I want to get a xml param ('fileSrc') in jquery.
What I should do?

My jquery code:
    
    `$xml = $("#my_xml_iframe").contents();

    //convert object to string or search for fileSrc

    alert($xml);`

My iframe:
    
    `<iframe id="my_xml_iframe" src="myFile.xml"></iframe>`

My xml (in iframe):
    
    `<reponse>

    <fileSrc>photo123.jpg</fileSrc>

    </response>`

I need code for search a object or convert to string. Anyone can help me?
btw: sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// get iframe html code
var xml = $("#my_xml_iframe").contents().find('body').html();
alert(xml);

// use regular expression to get the fileSrc
var pattern = /\<fileSrc\>(.*)\<\/fileSrc\>/i;
var fileSrc = pattern.exec(xml)[1];
alert(fileSrc);
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MLkd/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = $("#my_xml_iframe").contents().find('body').html();
console.log(xml);



var v = $(xml).find("fileSrc").text();
alert(v);
```

but parsing xml with DOM traversal methods is NOT good use instead [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CTfGe/1/

with .parseXML

```
var xml = "<reponse><fileSrc>photo123.jpg</fileSrc></reponse>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $fileSrc= $xml.find( "reponse");

alert($fileSrc.find("fileSrc").text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CTfGe/3/)

Comment: It doesn't work.  
For example:  
this is xml: http://farmereminencja.wrzuta.pl/xml/plik/6mdruY5dzxz/wrzuta.pl/sa/231231  
and i need to get a <fileId>

Comment: what doesnt work? the parsing ? in the fiddle it successfully retrieves the `filesrc`

Comment: yes, You enter a string into 'xml' variable. in my variable is a object. Try to do it with the example which i post above.